# Outer join two Datasets (not DataFrames) in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have some code that joins two streaming `DataFrames` and outputs to console.

```
val dataFrame1 =
  df1Input.withWatermark("timestamp", "40 seconds").as("A")

val dataFrame2 =
  df2Input.withWatermark("timestamp", "40 seconds").as("B")

val finalDF: DataFrame = dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2,
      expr(
        "A.id = B.id" +
          " AND " +
          "B.timestamp >= A.timestamp " +
          " AND " +
          "B.timestamp <= A.timestamp + interval 1 hour")
      , joinType = "leftOuter")
finalDF.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

What I now want is to refactor this part to use `Datasets`, so I can have some `compile-time` checking.

So what I tried was pretty straightforward:

```
val finalDS: Dataset[(A,B)] = dataFrame1.as[A].joinWith(dataFrame2.as[B],
      expr(
        "A.id = B.id" +
          " AND " +
          "B.timestamp >= A.timestamp " +
          " AND " +
          "B.timestamp <= A.timestamp + interval 1 hour")
      , joinType = "leftOuter")
finalDS.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

However, this gives the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream outer join between two streaming DataFrame/Datasets is not supported without a watermark in the join keys, or a watermark on the nullable side and an appropriate range condition;;

As you can see, the `join` code hasn't changed, so there is a watermark on both sides and a range condition. The only change was to use the `Dataset` API instead of `DataFrame`.

Also, it is fine when I use inner `join`:

```
val finalDS: Dataset[(A,B)] = dataFrame1.as[A].joinWith(dataFrame2.as[B],
          expr(
            "A.id = B.id" +
              " AND " +
              "B.timestamp >= A.timestamp " +
              " AND " +
              "B.timestamp <= A.timestamp + interval 1 hour")
          )
    finalDS.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

Does anyone know how can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you using `joinWith` method instead of `join` you rely on different implementation and it seems like this implementation not support *leftOuter join* for streaming Datasets.

You can check [outer joins with watermarking](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#outer-joins-with-watermarking) section of the official documentation. Method `join` not `joinWith` used. Note that result type will be `DataFrame`. That means that you most likely will have to map field manually

```
val finalDS = dataFrame1.as[A].join(dataFrame2.as[B],
    expr(
      "A.key = B.key" +
        " AND " +
        "B.timestamp >= A.timestamp " +
        " AND " +
        "B.timestamp <= A.timestamp + interval 1 hour"),
    joinType = "leftOuter").select(/* useful fields */).as[C]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, indeed I ended up doing this for the time being. Can I edit your answer to also add my solution (in which C is Tuple2[A,B], like the return type of joinWith). I'm aware in the docs that joinWith is not used, but maybe there is a way this can be achieved? I'll leave this open for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If you here for understnding why this exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream outer join between two streaming DataFrame/Datasets is not supported without a watermark in the join keys, or a watermark on the nullable side and an appropriate range condition;;
```

still aprears while you have introduced the watermark to the join and Spark 3 supports the streams join already, you probably have added watermarking AFTER the join, but Spark want you to add watermarking BEFORE the join on each stream!